# Ошибка в Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Selenium в пайтон не работает, выдаёт вот такую ошибку
Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
stdin=PIPE)
File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Артём\Desktop\Программы\Заказ\Krunker.py", line 4, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

В папке с файлом лежат хром драйвера, всё нужной версии, вот сам код

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print('Введите url')
web = input()
driver.get(web)
```

Comment: Уберите русские буквы из путей. Избежите в будущем множество непонятных ошибок при работе с питоном.  Лучше переставьте питон в короткий каталог. Например c:\python3\. Так же на всякий случай, не ставьте питон с microsoft store. Только с python.org

Answer (score 1):

Вы не ввели параметр `executable_path` в `webdriver.Chrome`. В `executable_path` должен быть путь к самому хромдрайверу.

Comment: Хром двайвер лежит в одной папке со скриптом

Comment: Путь указывать обязательно, просто напиши yourdriver.exe

Answer (score 1):

Отсутствует сам драйвер. Сначала скачайте его, называется chromedriver(.exe), далее из архива разархивируйте куда-то, и потом в коде в части driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/chromedriver.exe')

Answer (score 1):

**Import**

```
from pathlib import Path
```

**Code**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
pathToChromeDriver = f'{self.BASE_DIR}/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(pathToChromeDriver)
```

И закинь chromedriver в корень проекта